# Yesod: Non-exhaustive patterns in function isAuthorized

Tags: haskell, authorization, yesod

In a Yesod scaffolding project, I have added a new route and a new handler.

My error is the following:

```
29/Mar/2017:11:25:22 +0200 [Error#yesod-core] Foundation.hs:(137,5)-(144,45): Non-exhaustive patterns in function isAuthorized
 @(yesod-core-1.4.32-6HthMZNCl0sEMRz6GJ4QO1:Yesod.Core.Class.Yesod ./Yesod/Core/Class/Yesod.hs:693:5)
29/Mar/2017:11:25:22 +0200 [Debug#SQL] SELECT `ident`,`password` FROM `user` WHERE `id`=? ; [PersistInt64 1]
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is necessary to modify the Foundation.hs file, adding the new route to authorizations:

```
-- Routes not requiring authentication.
isAuthorized (AuthR _) _ = return Authorized
isAuthorized CommentR _ = return Authorized
isAuthorized HomeR _ = return Authorized
isAuthorized FaviconR _ = return Authorized
isAuthorized RobotsR _ = return Authorized
isAuthorized (StaticR _) _ = return Authorized
isAuthorized TestR _ = return Authorized

isAuthorized ProfileR _ = isAuthenticated
```

Comment: But then I get the following error:

"src\Foundation.hs:172:18: error:
    * The constructor `BookR' should have 1 argument, but has been given none
    * In the pattern: BookR
      In an equation for `isAuthorized':
          isAuthorized BookR _ = return Authorized
      In the instance declaration for `Yesod App'
    |
172 |     isAuthorized BookR _ = return Authorized"

Where my new BookR route looks like the following: "/book/#Text BookR GET", can I get some help what is missing?